# Dell iDRAC express and Broadcom Team

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing, drac

I have a few Dell servers that I'm trying to configure Broadcom NIC teams and use the iDRAC 6. It seems that when I setup a broadcom Smart Load Balancing(TM) and Failover (SLB) team, I loose connection to the iDRAC, the Dell rep said that it was probably the Broadcom BACS locking the LOM. Is there a way to have both?

```
  Team Software: BACS3 Version 12.2.9.0
  NICS: BCM5709C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with the 1.0 iDRAC6 firmware - it would fail when the NIC Teaming drivers kicked in on the Host operating system, this was seen with both Linux and Windows installations. The 1.5 iDRAC firmware resolves this - if you update that it should resolve your problem.

Comment: We are using Firmware 1.54 Build 15 with BIOS 2.1.15

Comment: Hmmh- interesting. What is the sharing mode set to?

Comment: Shared with failover all loms, but I think I might have gotten it working by downgrading from NIC firmware 5.0.6 -> 4.6.8

Comment: Interesting bug - good to know.

Comment: This seems to have worked for one of my servers, but not the other. I'll have to look into it more tomorrow.